# Some tasks never finish

Tags: vb.net, multithreading, task-parallel-library, task

I have a very weird problem related to TPL.
I am starting 20 worker threads that all execute the same method:

```
'Note that "Items" is BlockingCollection
Private Async Function SomeTask() As Task
    While Not Items.IsCompleted
    Dim item As New Tuple(Of Item, Decimal)(New Item(), 0)
        If (Items.TryTake(item, 1000)) Then
            Try
                Dim ProcessedItem = Await DoSomethingAsync(item)
            Catch ex As Exception
                'Error catching, simplified for this post
            End Try
        End If
    End While
End Function
```

In a main method, I am using await Task.WhenAll on a group of these tasks. 19 of 20 tasks finish correctly while 1 gets stuck. I have no idea what could be the problem here since they are all executing the same action.

Comment: I don't see an `Await` in your code. It's probably whatever is being done in the `Await` statement. Try to reduce the problem to a reproducible example that others can run.

Comment: Hello Stephen, I now edited the code. I was wondering, what could cause a thread to be stuck? I can't reproduce this issue except in that application. Why is is that it's always the last task stuck?

Comment: Did you call `CompleteAdding` before executing your tasks?

Comment: Yes. That is the weird part, 19 tasks finish (which means Items.IsCompleted is true - confirmed with debugger), but the last task gets stuck.

Comment: Usually, it is easier to solve such problems using stream processing. For example using PLINQ. I think you are down an unnecessarily hard path.

Comment: @matelras: Any number of things can cause a thread to be stuck. That's kind of like asking "what would cause this variable to have the value 3?" What you need to do is remove parts of the application until the problem *stops,* then look at the last thing you removed. No one here can help you unless we can reproduce the issue.